# Flutter Navigation: Failed assertion: line 4949 pos 12: 'newRoute._navigator == null': is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-navigation, supabase-flutter

My app uses Bloc as it's state management. When the app receive state `OAuthSignedIn()`, the `_navigator` in

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  log('Here');
  _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    HomePage.route,
    (route) => true,
  );
});
```

Gives error `'newRoute._navigator == null': is not true.`

Full code:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  App({super.key});

  final SupabaseClient supabaseClient = Supabase.instance.client;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AppBloc>(
      create: (context) => AppBloc(supabaseClient: supabaseClient),
      child: const AppView(),
    );
  }
}

class AppView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView({super.key});

  @override
  State<AppView> createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<AppView> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  NavigatorState get _navigator => _navigatorKey.currentState!;

  StreamSubscription<AuthState>? _authSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    handleOAuthListener();
    super.initState();
  }

  void handleOAuthListener() {
    SupabaseClient supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

    _authSubscription =
        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((AuthState data) {
      log("handleOAuthListener ${data.event.name}");
      handleOAuthSignIn(data);
    });
  }

  void handleOAuthSignIn(AuthState data) {
    final event = data.event;
    switch (event) {
      case AuthChangeEvent.initialSession:
        log("Getting initial user");
        context.read<AppBloc>().add(GetInitialUser());

      case AuthChangeEvent.signedIn:
        log("OAuth Sign in success");
        context.read<AppBloc>().add(OAuthSignInSuccessfullEvent());

      case AuthChangeEvent.tokenRefreshed:
        log("OAuth token refreshed");
        context.read<AppBloc>().add(OAuthSignInSuccessfullEvent());
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _authSubscription?.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return BlocListener<AppBloc, AppState>(
          listenWhen: (previous, current) => current != previous,
          listener: (context, state) {
            switch (state) {
              case OAuthSignedIn():
                WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  log('Here');
                  _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    HomePage.route,
                    (route) => true,
                  );
                });
                break;

              case OAuthSignedOut():
                WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  log('Signed out here');
                  _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    LoginPage.route,
                    (route) => true,
                  );
                });
                break;

              default:
                break;
            }
          },
          child: child,
        );
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (_) => SplashPage.route,
    );
  }
}
```

I did tried changing the `WidgetsBinding` to `ScheduleBinding` and using `Future.delayed` (with various durations) instead of both bindings, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue

Also, using `Future.delayed` changed the error to `'!_debugLocked': is not true.`

Comment: fell into navigating without `context` meme. using bang operator `_navigatorKey.currentState!` then surprised when it is not null safe.  try to use `Navigator.of(context)`